# Extending the Visual Studio 2010 C# Intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, plugins, add-in

Basically I would like to add extend the IntelliSense of Visual Studio 2010 (C#). Is it possible somehow?

We use objects generated at runtime - thus IntelliSense doesn't work for them. We have methods for getting their structure elsewhere, and it would be nice if they could seamlessly extend the normal IntelliSense.

If it's not possible, is there an alternate approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following post can be usefull to you:

[How to extend IntelliSense items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133887/how-to-extend-intellisense-items)

Hope that I helped.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what i need. Searched a ton for it but never found anything as spot on as that one. Thanks a lot!