# RTL comments in XML Comments intellisense displays words in reverse order

Tags: .net, visual-studio, intellisense, right-to-left, xml-documentation

I have an SRS written in RTL language (Hebrew) that can't be touched.

I translated the Hebrew names in the SRS. Of course I want to be able to understand the meaning of a value in my enum (or any other object)

I did the following

```
enum Objects
{
    /// <summary>אזעקה</summary> // <=== the hebrew name (RTL)
    Alarm,
    /// <summary>סיבת אזעקה</summary> // <=== the hebrew name (RTL)
    Alarm_Reason
}
```

Now when I write `Objects.Alarm`, IntelliSense properly displays `"אזעקה"`.

However, when I write `Objects.Alarm_Reason`, IntelliSense wrongly displays `"אזעקה סיבת "` instead of properly displaying `"סיבת אזעקה"`. The order of words is switched!

Is there any way to fix this?

Microsoft [suggests that there is no way around the issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/458384/xml-intellisence-and-right-to-left-languages#details), but I hoped someone would have an idea for a workaround?

Would creating a VS2010 plugin that will force IntelliSense to accept RTL properly be possible?

Comment: I copy pasted the code but I get this error instead: http://i.imgur.com/bQOIY.png Any ideea why?

Comment: @RăzvanPanda no idea. probably installing hebrew language pack will solve this. writting none english comments is generally a bad practice because of this. but this will make ussing my SRS much easier.

Comment: Did you enter the two words using copy paste or keyboard input?

Comment: A little late, but I am currently struggling with this issue. It is possible to insert Unicode characters into XML comments by their code: `&#1488;` inserts an **א**. Perhaps it is possible to fix this using the [Unicode directional formatting codes](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Directional_Formatting_Codes).

Comment: hi @ZevSpitz please post here if you can provide a working solution.

Comment: For your purposes it may be enough to put `&#8235;` after the `<summary>` start tag. It didn't help me (nor did any of the variations I tried), because I need to embed LTR strings within the RTL text. Try this, and I'll post as an answer if it works.

Comment: You're probably aware that unless you are certain that you'll be the only person using this code, using a language other than English in comments is a bad idea, as it will prevent anyone who doesn't speak the langauge from benefiting from your comments. The only reason I need something like this is for teaching purposes, when the students are beginning programmers and not fluent enough in English.

Comment: thats not entierly true. not everyone works in  a big company with very skilled programers that are fluent in english.
there are MANY small oraganizations where some programers even with CSbsc that have trouble understanding english as embraressing as it sounds. 
there is no way that the project will EVER be read by someone who is not totally fluent in Hebrew. but the issue here is that the requirments and SRS are written in hebrew. and I need a comfortable way to map between Hebrew and English terms. the client requires all the documents be in hebrew etc etc..

Comment: Point taken. Did you have any success with the override code?

Comment: No. I did not :( thanks for trying.

Answer (score 1):

Adding hebrew input language and activating might make it work as intended:

[image]

And then try inserting/pasting the 2 words again in the XML.

**Update**

From what I read I reached the same conclusion, that it is not possible with basic visual studio functionality.

As you said, it might be a good idea to write a plugin to transform the summary in the RTL form when displaying the tool tip.

Following links might be of use:

[CSharp Intellisense](http://csharpintellisense.codeplex.com/)

[Custom Intellisense Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460138/custom-intellisense-extension)

[How to extend IntelliSense items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133887/how-to-extend-intellisense-items)

Comment: Also try Hebrew with US keyboard.