# How to stop VisualStudio from expanding everything when deleting { } brackets

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring

I asked this question few days ago and didn't get an answer, so I'll try again precising it a little.

I like to keep my code rolled up by collapsing methods, comments and xml summaries that I don't use at the moment. However, every time I edit some braces in a method, loop, switch statement or any part of the code (anything containing `{` or `}` brace), everything below expands after 1 second. Everything unfolds all the way down till the end of current file (or region, if edited code lies within it).

I can't take it anymore I'm tired of using `Ctrl`+`M`+`O` all the time and then re-finding edited field again. Is there any option or extension for VS2010, that would solve my problem?

**Update**
I'm starting to realize there's no way to solve the problem. However I could also accept an answer to a modified question: **Is there a way or tool that would allow me to automatically delete `{` and `}` brace pairs containing only 1 instruction?** It'd be an acceptable workaround for my problem.

Comment: Do you really do this a lot? Can't see any reason to do this kind of refactoring personally, I'd just deal with it seeing as eventually you will run out of places to refactor (I've spent the day removing regions too but thats a different subject)

Comment: That was an example, but I meant code overall editing - cuting, pasting, changing and all the stuff. It's not like I write a perfect code that I'll never have to edit again.

Comment: I've just been looking out of curiosity and I think `Options>Text Editor>Formatting>General>Auto Complete on }` will be causing it, the } will be changing to closing the method, auto formatting the code between the methods braces

Comment: This option just autoformats everything within `{}` when you put `}`, but my problem lies in expanding everything beyond those braces.

Comment: I've never faced such behavior and my only suggestion is to reset your visual studio settings through `Tools -> Import and Export Settings` and `Reset all settings` option.

Comment: @Tarec I also find this behavior quite annoying when editing and don't know of a solution (although I must admit it is not so annoying that I spent time looking for a solution). Hence the upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using folding myself for a static class containing localization text, and it is pretty nice to be able to `hide`/`show` things, similar to how `TreeView` does with nodes:

[image: Static strings]

And I have never ever faced the described problem or been annoyed with something that `VS` does.

However, when you are editing code, such behavior is a bit too much for `Intellisense` I think (as already described in another answer). Perhaps you should change your "way of thinking" ?

Take a look:

[image: Members list]

You can quickly navigate between members or have a brief overview of them by using this special window, while having all the code unfolded.

I have seen some people like `#region` much. But you can achieve the same (if not better in all measures) by using `partial` and splitting single class into pieces.

p.s.: and with last your question, why don't you just select first what you need to delete and then press `Delete` ? Or what would that tool do for you? Automatically go through sources, detect that and delete? If you are a programmer, then making software that will do that shouldn't take more than writing you question here =D

Comment: Because I cannot choose "{" and "}" at the same time when there's code between it, that I don't want to delete. I took a look at the navigation thing you showed me and although it's not really solving my problem in any way, it is a helpful tool to use. Thank you.

Comment: I see. What would be possible to do is a sort of clipboard monitor program. You have to delete the whole function with `Control`+`Delete` and this program will read content of clipboard, remove `{` and `}` and put back only code part. Theoretically there are already tools to *play* with clipboard content, but you can make your own quickly.

Comment: I marked that answer as a correct one, but it's the comment above that I found to be the best idea. I've managed to write a program that reacts for some key-pair by copying selected fragment and pasting it automatically without outer braces. That's definately the way to go for me, thank you.

Comment: I just came with another idea. You can also simply comment the code, edit it and then un-comment. This should keep `Intellisense` in the house ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If I understand what you need then you are asking `how to stop the code below the line that I am editing from automatically expanding.`I would like to tell there is no solution either from official sources or anything.Code collapsing a feature of ideal code editors like Visual Studio.

Let me explain you why this happens and how to prevent it.First let me explain essential conditions for code collapsing to work.Ideal code editors make use of Lexers and Parsers for the language the support,parsers make use of regular expressions to match language specific syntax entered by Coder or someone,in this sequence code editor stores all the locations where specific symbols like `;`,`{ and }`,`"`.

In order for code collapsing to work effectively there must be equal number of theses symbols specified in exact order in the code being edited,whenever there is something in the source code which does not match the language specific syntax the parser flags reports the editing and formatting engine of this error.

Coming back to your problem,lets talk about what you face,to better understand it lets consider a simple code block;

[image: Code Collapsing works perfectly upto this point]

and consider there are more functions below `AddNumbers` that are also collapsed.Now If I understood you,then you said if `I edit`MultiplyNumbers`and remove its starting curly brace`{`,the all the code below this point automatically expands.

[image: Misplaced starting curly brace]

If this is the case then the problem is because parser tries to match the language syntax and searches for any terminating curly braces below this point which is found in `AddNumbers's` terminating curly brace.

**Update :**

In one line,there is no solution to this problem,this is because Visual Studio performs Real time parsing,that's how it shows you errors at real time.Actually this is not a problem that's why this has never been reported due to which there is nothing available from official sources.However you can prevent this by changing you coding habits a bit,like when you are creating a function suppose SomeFunction(int a,int b),try to first complete the outer side of function like below;

```
private void SomeFunction(int a,int b)
{
//Write code later.
}
```

First create the function outline as above and then write some code in it like below;

```
private void SomeFunction(int a,int b)
{
int z=a+b;
Console.WriteLine(z);

int x=a*b;
Console.WriteLine(x);

int p=a/b;
Console.WriteLine(p);

int q=a-b;
Console.WriteLine(q);
}
```

Next consider you are writing an `if statement`,first complete the outer side like this;

```
if(//We'll define condition later)
{
//Write function body later.
}
```

If you've used code snippets in Visual Studio,then you might have noticed Visual Studio generates the snipett's outer side first,then it places the caret to first argument.

So,these are some guidelines,something that can prevent the issue.

Now head towards solution,`to prevent this situation when you create a function try to first place its { and } braces before writing any code in it.`

Hope this prevents the issue you are facing.If there's anything more you are facing please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You got my problem 100% right. However I do understand why does that happen, but I don't understand why can't VS just parse the code without expanding it. I didn't quite understand what did you mean with solution you gave me - I can't imagine writing a method body without puting braces first:) But when I see a 1-line loop for example, I tend to delete its braces to make the code clearer, but then all the mess happens.  Also, the code doesn't expand when I delete the left brace `{` first, so maybe I just need to change my habbits..

Comment: But as I told you, I don't understand the solution you gave me. Could you please be more speciffic?

Comment: Thank you, but that's how I do write my methods (can anyone really do it otherwise?). My problem shows up when editing braces like in the first example you've provided. I've also updated my question so maybe some workaround could be found.

Comment: @Tarec As a last word word I would like to tell you I googled the net many times searched official sources,but unfortunately there is nothing that can be done,the only workaround is to change your code editing habits.See there are more than millions of programmers out of which majority uses Visual Studio,but even after a year of release of Visual Studio,this issue has never been reported to it's official owners.This only means one thing,this is not a serious issue and you can overcome it by changing your code editing habits a little bit.

Comment: I came here looking for an answer to this equally annoying problem, but after reading this, I see how a solution is neither possible nor desired.  If you've ever used an older version of Eclipse, you know what doing a bad job at collapsing means.  VS has never messed up and collapsed the wrong sections, and I think that's due in part to this behavior: on error, expand all.  I agree it's annoying, but I am trying to be cognizant of that and adjust my methods a bit.
I wish they had a way to collapse all and then auto-expand to the current cursor position like some other editors can. Oh well :)

Comment: Just a thought since I found my way back here almost a year later...  What about a feature to wrap/unwrap the selected text in curly braces, similar to Refactor -> Surround With?  You could select the text you wanted to modify, choose "Refactor -> Surround With -> Curly Braces".  Similarly, when you've selected a section that is already wrapped in braces, it should offer the option to REMOVE braces.

Let's say you have a 1 line IF without braces and you need to add another line. Just select the 1 line and wrap in braces instead of risking auto-expansion of all the code.  It's so useful!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what the issue is here, as this certainly doesn't seem like normal behaviour (I've never experienced it).

There are a few options though (without knowing more about the problem) that might help you.

Firstly, someone has given a very good answer on another thread about customising the visual studio intellisense: [Custom Intellisense Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460138/custom-intellisense-extension)

If that isn't an option, perhaps have a look at the extensions that are provided for Visual Studio 2010.

Productivity Power Tools might help you out with some of your refactoring. You can get this through Visual Studio by going to Tools - Extension Mananger. And then select the option and Install it.
Power Tools is quite limited so this might not be enough. I'm sure people can offer other alternatives but I would certainly recommend ReSharper: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/.
You can get a free trial but after that period you have to pay for it. I use it and the extensions it provides are fantastic. You can completely change the way Visual Studio behaves for your personal preferences.

Sorry I can't offer any other help, but if you can provide some more information then maybe we can find a solution (e.g. What do you mean by other methods are expanding etc).

Comment: I'm afraid it's not the case. I've updated the question. It's not a problem of refactoring itself, but of code editing. That was just an example :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this problem that you encounter is a universal one and it can be sometimes irritating.   In my experience, visual studio goes haywire especially when you are writing a lot of block statements in a large code file, whenever such happens you can save your work and restart VS. But to answer your question, make sure that you first try to open any collapsed code you want to edit and as for copying/cutting try to highlight the collapsed code first before carrying out of the editing options this informs the editor that you want to edit the highlighted segment of code. Hope it helps

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand.. I'd be glad If you could explain it a bit more. How am I supposed to edit the code, that's highlighted?

Comment: Hi, @Tarec are you sure that it is not an extension in your visual studio that is causing the misnomer? As for removing braces and re-factoring your code base maybe you should check [resharper](www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), it does a great job on that

Comment: I've disabled all of extensions to check it and the problem remains. But I'll check resharper as it's been recommended many times to me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: vs options]

Maybe this can be of some help ?

Comment: Not the case, sorry :)