# CSS !important declaration in Visual Studio Express

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to add !important declaration to Visual Studio 2013/2012 Express Intellisense? 
I know the declaration is included in Web Essentials, but the extension is not available for Express versions.

Comment: You could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460138/custom-intellisense-extension . Hope this helps

Comment: Actually the only way is to make a custom Intellisence, but for now I have no luck creating it. Although - thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to add !important declaration in Visual Studio Express 2013 - [Web Essentials 2013 Update 2](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361). This extension have implemented "!important" into Intellisence, as well as some other nice features for Web Development.