# How to get intellisense to autocomplete generic class angle brackets

Tags: c#, generics, intellisense

I'm currently working with visual studio 2013. This is more of an annoyance than anything else, but when I make, say, a List, that contains a generic class, how do I get Intellisense to spit out the angle brackets and series of class stand-ins?

For example, if I type

```
new Lis
```

The Intellisense dropdown will highlight List<>

however, when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Space</kbd>/etc, I get

```
new List
```

When I would rather have

```
new List<T>
```

Where T is highlighted and ready to be replaced.

Is this an option somewhere in visual studio?

Comment: I don't believe you can do this for VS 2013... you can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460138/custom-intellisense-extension) but it sounds like that's just for new stuff, not to extend existing like you're looking for. In VS2015, the access to Roslyn allows you to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a setting for such things.

But, there is a tool called Resharper that do something like what you need. Instead of replacing `T` you get an empty `<|>` with the cursor ready to write the `type`.

```
new List<|>
```

**Note:** There may be other tools that do the same.