# Can Intellisense be programatically accessed by a VS plugin. Adding editor support via plugin for language not supported by VS

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, intellisense

I am writing a Scheme interpreter as a plugin to VS.  I want to use intellisense for symbol completion.

Is this possible?  Can I programmatically pass symbols to intellisense so the plugin user can see available symbols?

Comment: See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166533.aspx

Comment: have a look on the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460138/custom-intellisense-extension