# Create method dynamically where return type is known at compiletime

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

given following class:

```
public class Stock {
   public string Name;
   public double Price;
}
```

and I have following DataFactory:

```
public class DataFactory {
   public Stock Stock = new Stock();   

   public DataFactory Name(string name) {
     Stock.name = name;
     return this;
   }

   public DataFactory Price(double price) {
      Stock.Price = price;
      return this;
   }
}
```

can following code:

```
.....
   new DataFactory().Name("ATVI").Price(50)
....
```

be written as:

```
....
   new DataFactory().ATVI().Price(50)
....
```

without implementing ATVI() on the factory? 
This will work if i create the method dynamically beforehand. But is this also possible without knowing what method will be called? So i am looking for some hook at lifetime that notifies me about unknown properties/methods.

And if this works, can Price() at compile time be called with intellisense?

No idea how this can be called so sorry if duplicate threads exist.

Best regards
Josef

Comment: Do you just hate writing string literals, or do you just hate writing `Name`?

Comment: If you derive your datafactory from DynamicObject, you could override TryGetMethod. But I doubt there is a way to provide intellisense,

Comment: @Sweeper I understand that this sounds a bit weird. But currently I want to write unit tests for a tool. To do this I will need some test data. I though about moving all those unwanted stuff into a data factory. Then I was thinking of how I can remove the need to write Name() all over again. The idea is that if any string literal is given, i always know that this is the stock symbol. Of course it will be a fancy feature if this works. So it is more experimentally in my case.

Comment: @KlausGütter Thanks. I will try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming you have a finite pre-defined set of text literals that does not change often**, you could just generate an enumeration (or even a class of string constants) using `T4` templates for example, and use it like:
`DataFactory.Name(Tickers.ATVI).Price(50)`
That would be an approach that best matches semantics of the problem and abilities of C# language and tooling.

By the way, that method chaining you're planning to use is a combination of *builder pattern* and *fluent interface*, [see an example in c#](http://www.stefanoricciardi.com/2010/04/14/a-fluent-builder-in-c/)

If you still want to have this concealed as a method call, you have a couple of options:

1. Pre - Generate list of methods using `T4` templates in a *partial class* or as *extension methods* to your data factory. You could select a list of literals from you data store inside your `T4` template. This is a fairly common approach. Since you will have the methods pre-generated, itellisence will work with this approach. [read more about T4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2017)
2. Use `DLR` and `dynamic`. This will defer method lookup until runtime, and you can create a custom dynamic object that will accept any method call, and then take that method name and pass it as an argument to your `Name` method. Intellisence won't work with this approach since you don't have any metadata in the assembly regarding your methods. [How to create a dynamic object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/walkthrough-creating-and-using-dynamic-objects)
3. Use `dynamic` and additionally create an intellisence extension, see [Custom Intellisense Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460138/custom-intellisense-extension) for more details

You coud go even further, and write an `Roslyn` analyzer, and install it in your Visual Studio to have automatic code fixes from `DataFactory().Name("ATVI")` to `DataFactory().ATVI()`, that is - if you have the time/resource. Check out [example of code analyzer](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix)

As always, the answer is "it depends", and context is everything, so it is hard to tell which solution will be best for you.
I would rather go for the simplest one 1), especially keeping in mind the complexity and maintenance cost of 2) and 3)

Please let me know if you need more details on any of the options
Hope it helps!

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks for all the options. I think I will try all of them and decide then what I should use. I will come back if I need further assistance.

Comment: Glad I could help, @JosefBiehler!

Answer (score 0):

the following code

```
new DataFactory().Name("ATVI").Price(50)
```

cannot be written as

```
new DataFactory().ATVI().Price(50)
```

in fact, none of those codes works. because you can't get function "Price" from the function "Name" and "ATVI()" is not a valid function

I'm not sore what you're trying to accomplish, the given code will return a function.
but if I'm not mistaken you to want to set "Price" by "Name". 
then what I think you need is the Class [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

I tried to come up with a nice function or anything like that but I don't really know what you're are after...

Comment: As you can see in my code example, `Name()` returns an instance of type `DataFactory` and not a function? So yes, this code should work, though i have not tested it but written it on the fly while writing this question. Maybe I don't understand exactly your point :-)