# Custom autocomplete for Visual Studio or ReSharper

Tags: autocomplete, resharper, ini, visual-studio-extensions

I'm working with a game engine named ORX which is data driven. That means, that you define object behaviours, configurations, etc. in .ini files, making it possible to change things without recompiling your code. There are two template files for how to write these .ini files for your game: [CreationTemplate.ini](https://github.com/orx/orx/blob/master/code/bin/CreationTemplate.ini) and [SettingsTemplate.ini](https://github.com/orx/orx/blob/master/code/bin/SettingsTemplate.ini).

What I would like to achieve is an autocompletion feature for Visual Studio (or if it's not possible, then for ReSharper), where in a new .ini file the IDE uses this two templates to suggest solutions.

I haven't found any options to extend the existing autocomplete functionality with custom rules, so I'm thinking about writing an extension for it. Only, I have never done this before and I have no idea where to start or how hard/long would it be/take.

Could you give me some tips and starting points for this project? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460138/custom-intellisense-extension).

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT, thank you. I tried to find a solution on my own, but couldn't find this. I'll check it out and comment again if it's not suitable for my needs.

Comment: Thanks for your any feedback.