# In the extension development of Visual Studio, is there an API similar to the effect of the Decoration API in the extension of VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-extensions, github-copilot

I am developing a code completion extension. I have achieved the effect in the figure below in both VSCode and Jetbrains IDE, that is, the completion content is displayed in gray text behind the code. In VSCode, I can achieve it through the **Decoration API**. In Jetbrains, I can achieve it by rendering a piece of text behind the cursor through **EditorCustomElementRenderer**. I like this completion method very much. The well-known completion tool Copilot also uses this mode. I have checked a lot of documents, but I still can't find how to implement it in **Visual Studio**. I want to see how to implement this in Visual Studio, many thanks!

[VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQTwB.png)  [JetBrains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrS30.png)

I researched related documents and tools and found that in VS2019, similar effects cannot be achieved. But Copilot achieves something similar in VS2022. Wondering which API he used? It would be even better if there is such an API in VS2019.

If there is really no related API, I would like to know if there is an API that can render a piece of text near the cursor, which can be in the form of tooltips or something else, similar to the following effect.

[tootips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4wZe.png)

What I hope is that I can control through code when to display this prompt near the cursor.

**To summarize my problem is as follows**

1. In VS2019, is there an API for rendering a piece of text behind the cursor, similar to **Decortaion API** in VSCode

2. If not in VS2019, is there any in VS2022?

3. If not, is there a similar API that can display a piece of text behind the cursor? Which can be in the form of tooltips or something else.

Comment: IntelliCode also has something likes this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/intellicode/intellicode-visual-studio

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72537148/3740047