# Visual Studio 2010/Resharper Plugin development

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, resharper, intellisense

I am having trouble tracking down information regarding extending Intellisense. It looks like creating a plugin for VS 2010 or Resharper would do the trick. However, I can't find any documentation for adding items to the intellisense dropdown.

This post got pretty close: [How to extend IntelliSense items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133887/how-to-extend-intellisense-items)

But I couldn't find any documentation for the interfaces or classes being used.

What I am trying to do is to read from an XML file, and add those tags as part of the results that show up in intellisense in the C# code (not in XML).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of the R# Plugin Development Guide concerning Code Completion (i.e., IntelliSense) is on our todo list but has not yet been written. When done, it should be available [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6+Plugin+Development). While we're working on that, feel free to email me dn at jetbrains dot com, and I'll try to help you out with any queries you might have.