# Custom Intellisense Presenter problems

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I am creating my own intellisense presenter these days, and I have posted this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736884/how-to-add-a-button-to-visual-studio-intellisense) and downloaded this [editor sample](http://editorsamples.codeplex.com/).
After run the sample, I found some problems, but didn't find how to solve them.

**1.** If I input one character, the recommended API description in the right displays well, but in the left, the API list lists all of APIs without recommended API focus. Only when I input the second character, the list will focus on the recommended API.

**2.** There's no `scrollviewBar`, I change the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` from **Hidden** to **Auto** at line **85** in the *CompletionSessionView.xaml* file, the scrollbar appears. But, when I click down arrow of the scrollbar, it doesn't work well, some API may inputted into the editor.

**3.** When I use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete the input, the Intellisense will not disappear in time. For example, if I input *a* in the editor, intellisense appears, then I delete *a*, the intellisense still there, only if I press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> again, the intellisense will disappear.

Is there an article introduce how to create intellisense presenter? There's little comments in the sample, hardly understand the code.

Answer (score 1):

A really new thing is being added to C# and it is called Roslyn. With Roslyn you can write your own intellisense using C# and I have to say its pretty simple.

First: Download http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx

Second: Read and Try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/302595/Roslyn-CTP-Three-Introductory-Projects

Honestly it is really really easy. Bye!